# Background color in HTML is not applied to the whole page

Tags: html, css, web

I made the background of the body gray . I added a picture to the body part but the back of the picture is white. but the back of the h4 sticker is gray . why the back of the picture is not gray .It happens if I manually give the basement px but I want it to do it automatically.

HTML CODES

```
<body class="body" style="background-color: #212325" > 
    
    <h4 class="h4"> <i style="color: yellow;" class="bi bi-upload"></i> Dikkat Çeken Yeni Diziler</h4>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="box">
      <a href="">  <img style="width: 200px; height: 300px;" src="assets/images/thePianist.jpg" alt="Shadow and Bone" ></a>
      </div>  
    </div>
   
     
</body>
```

CSS CODES

```
.h4{
    color: rgb(214, 214, 214);
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.body{
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.container {
    width: 80%;
    padding: 80px 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    float: left;
}

.box {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background: gray;
    margin: 0px 14px;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.box img {border-radius: 0px;}

.box:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1);
    background: black;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

It Look Like This :

[unwanted image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcuxU.png)

I Want it look like this :

[wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VB2N5.png)

Comment: If you wish, please show me a link to check.

Comment: I could help more if you gave a link. I could look into the source code and inpect element to help me understand which div is display what.

Comment: Could you explain what “ It happens if I manually give the basement px” means? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have a style applied to the `<h4>` tag. However, you have none applied as a blanket to the `<body>` tag or your container class that would apply a gray color to it. If you want the same color from the `<h4>` tag to your container class, then try adding the same line of code for color from your `<h4>` CSS to your container CSS, which would make the container CSS look like this:

```
.container {
    color: rgb(214, 214, 214);
    width: 80%;
    padding: 80px 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    float: left;
}
```

This should fix your issue, but if it doesn't, there may be an error that I overlooked. Let me know either way, and have a good day.

Comment: Interestingly, when I gave the background color to the body in the style.css section, it worked automatically. I didn't need to give it a pixel.When I gave the container a background color, only the inside of the container became white, but the way I wrote above it was fixed, thanks

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, I can only suggest this change hoping it works.

```
.container {
    width: 80%;
    padding: 80px 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    float: left;
}
```

to

```
.container {
    width: 80%;
    padding: 80px 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    float: left;
    background: rgb(214, 214, 214);
}
```

The container is the div holding the box div which is displayed as a movie cover. The empty space would be the container.

If this doesn't work try changing backgroud of each div 1 by 1 to see which div it is.

Comment: Interestingly, when I gave the background color to the body in the style.css section, it worked automatically. I didn't need to give it a pixel.When I gave the container a background color, only the inside of the container became white, but the way I wrote above it was fixed, thanks